# Reading a XML file and echoing it to the console

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have a requirement to echo the XML in human-readable format to the command prompt, preferably to keep it looking EXACTLY like the XML does.

When I do

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fsInput = fs.OpenTextFile("\\PATH",1)
WScript.Echo fsInput.ReadAll
```

It gives me a singular line of text...so I assume it reads the XML as one line instead of traversing the nodes and outputting them. So this doesn't work. I've been googling for the last hour and I can't find what I need unfortunately.

Here is an example of what my XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<Configuration Date="12/3/2012 4:32:30 PM"> 
   <Sys_Info>
      <Name>CEJHUI34</Name> 
      <Manufacturer>LENOVO</Manufacturer> 
      <Model>7826</Model> 
      <Serial_Number>N/A</Serial_Number> 
      <Operating_System>"Microsoft Windows 7"</Operating_System> 
      <OS_Version>"Professional "</OS_Version> 
      <IP_Address>1.5.1.85</IP_Address>
      <CPU_per_Domain>1</CPU_per_Domain>
      <CPU_Speed_MHz>6984</CPU_Speed_MHz>
      <RAM>3176.45 MB</RAM>
   </Sys_Info> 
   <Configuration-Tasks> 
      <task> 
         <name>All updates loaded</name> 
         <result>PASS</result> 
         <comment></comment> 
      </task> 
     <task> 
        <name>Accounts Setup</name>
        <result>FAIL</result>
        <comment>No Guest account</comment>
     </task>
  </Configuration-Tasks> 
</Configuration >
```

Any ideas on what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ReadAll()`, use `ReadLine()` and output each line individually:

```vb
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fsInput = fs.OpenTextFile("\\PATH",1)

do until fsInput.AtEndOfStream
    WScript.Echo fsInput.ReadLine()
loop

fsInput.Close
```

Comment: This still prints it all as one big wall of text. I think when VBScript is reading it, it brings it in as one long line...

Comment: it could be the newline character used in your XML file